# How to stop evaluating if the first condion has been passed

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I try to evaluate a field in my report but it fails every time :

```
= IIf(Fields!lectcrs_hrs.IsMissing,
      Round(Fields!lectcrs_fee.Value * "1.00", 2),
      Round(Fields!lectcrs_fee.Value * Fields!lectcrs_hrs.Value, 2))
```

---

in the case of `Fields!lectcrs_hrs.IsMissing = true` my field is empty and i find that the reason that the second case `Round(Fields!lectcrs_fee.Value * Fields!lectcrs_hrs.Value, 2)` contains a missing field `Fields!lectcrs_hrs` .why it checks the second case if it passes the first one !

How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are looking for is called "short-circuiting" and, unfortunately, the IIf function in Visual Basic does not offer that. The reason being is that IIf() is a ternary **function** and, as such, all arguments passed into it are evaluated **before** the function call occurs. A ternary **operator** (If() in VB 9+), on the other hand, does support conditional evaluation. However, I do not believe that the If() operator can be used as a part of an expression in SSRS.

Given the fact that you are trying to use a field which may or may not exist at run time, I suggest that you create a custom function in your report to handle the proper checking and return values. For reference, take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2009/07/06/ssrs-and-mdx-detecting-missing-fields/), which covers the same scenario.